# Why can't I call kotlin suspend function under lambda function

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Let me start with example code snippets

```
suspend fun executeLive(result: MutableLiveData<Person>) {

    val response = ... //suspend api request

    mediatorLiveData.removeSource(response)

    mediatorLiveData.addSource(response) {
        result.value = sortData(it) // sortData is also suspend function which sortData at Dispatcher.Default
    }

}
```

In this example, `sortData` can't call under `lambda function`(in this case `addSource`).And also I already declare `executeLive` as `suspend`, that why `suspend` api request can start at first. But `sortData` function show compile time error

> Suspend function can only be called from a coroutine body

So how do I change my code structure to solve this problems?

**Update:** Is there any article about this?

Comment: You can `launch` a coroutine that will set the value on the result. But you should have access to the appropriate `CoroutineScope` to avoid leaks.

Comment: You can try with `runBlocking { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

A lambda is generally a callback function. Callback functions are so called because we wrap a block of code in a function, and pass it to someone else (or some place else) to be executed. It is a basic inversion of control where the code is not for you to execute, but someone else to do it (example the framework).

For example when you set a `onClickListener` on a button, we don't know when it will get called, we pass a lambda for the framework which takes care of the user interaction to call the specified action.

In your case similarly the suspend function is not calling the `sortdata`, it is passing it to the `mediatorLiveData` object to call it in its own context. It is not necessary the lambda you passed would be called from a coroutine body, as such this is not allowed.

Comment: I would just add that it would work if `addSource` were an inline function (and its argument not `crossinline`), thus guaranteeing it's calling the lambda in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by converting the `mediatorLiveData.addSource` call into a suspending call itself with `suspendCoroutine`:

```
suspend fun executeLive(result: MutableLiveData<Person>) {

    val response = ... //suspend api request

    mediatorLiveData.removeSource(response)

    val data = suspendCoroutine<TypeOfData> { cont ->
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(response) { cont.resume(it) }
    }

    result.value = sortData(data)
}
```

I've used `TypeOfData` as a placeholder for whatever the type of data emitted by `response` is. Note that this will only work if the you're intending for a single emission to happen, though.

If you need to track multiple values, you can experiment with `callbackFlow`:

```
suspend fun executeLive(result: MutableLiveData<Person>) {

    val response = ... //suspend api request

    mediatorLiveData.removeSource(response)

    callbackFlow<TypeOfData> {
        mediatorLiveData.addSource(response) { offer(it) }

        awaitClose { mediatorLiveData.removeSource(response) }
    }
        .collect { result.value = sortData(it) }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are 3 working examples:

First:

```kotlin
override suspend fun findReport(date: LocalDate): ByteArray? {
        val sql = """select report from reports_table where report_date = :date"""
        val map = MapSqlParameterSource("date", date)

        return suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
            jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, map) { rs, _ ->
                val param = rs.getString("report")
                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                    continuation.resumeWith(Result.success(encryptService.decompressAndDecryptFile(param))) // decompressAndDecryptFile() is suspending function
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Second:

```kotlin
override suspend fun findReport(date: LocalDate): ByteArray? {
        val sql = """select report from reports_table where report_date = :date"""
        val map = MapSqlParameterSource("date", date)
        val deferred = CompletableDeferred<ByteArray?>()
        jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(sql, map) { rs, _ ->
            val param = rs.getString("report")
            CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
                val result =
                    encryptService.decompressAndDecryptFile(param) // decompressAndDecryptFile() is suspending function
                deferred.complete(result)
            }
        }
        return deferred.await()
    }
```

Last one - use `runBlocking { }` But in this case, you will block the current thread until the coroutine is executed:

```kotlin
override suspend fun findReport(date: LocalDate): ByteArray? {
        val sql = """select report from reports_table where report_date = :date"""
        val map = MapSqlParameterSource("date", date)
        return jdbcTemplate.query(sql, map, ResultSetExtractor { rs ->
            if (rs.next()) {
                val encodedFileEntry = rs.getString("report")
                runBlocking {
                    encryptService.decompressAndDecryptFile(encodedFileEntry)
                }
            } else {
                log.warn("There is no report for the date: $date")
                null
            }
        })
    }
```